# Preferance file not call

Tags: magento2

*MagentoCoders/Invoicepdf/etc/di.xml*
`<?xml version="1.0"?> <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd"> <preference for="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Totals" type="MagentoCoders\Invoicepdf\Block\Sales\Order\Totals"/> </config>`

Comment: check for permission to generated folder